Create a bottomsheet in Compose with a scrollable content when it is half expanded
I have BottomSheetScaffold containing a Column as a sheetContent. When the bottomsheet is first opened, it's half expanded, and I want to be able to scroll inside the content without expanding the bottomsheet. But when I drag/swipe the header, it must expand totally.
I try several possibilities

use the modifier .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) to the Column => the bottomsheet always expands, and the content scrolls only after that.
limit the height of the Column with Box(modifier = Modifier.height(300.dp)) and avoid swiping with sheetSwipeEnabled = false => the content scrolls well but the bottomsheet can't expand anymore.

So, do you have any solution to combine both? I hope it's possible without creating a total custom component.
Thanks
EDIT
I still need help
BottomSheetScaffold(scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetSwipeEnabled = myUiState.isBottomSheetSwipeEnable
        sheetContent = {
            SheetContent(
                changeSheetSwipeEnable = myUiState.changeSheetSwipeEnable
            )}
        }) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            
        }
}

I create a changeSheetSwipeEnable boolean in uistate that is modify in viewmodel. changeSheetSwipeEnable is sent to sheetContent and managed when user drag from the header of the bottomsheet or not, and it works well. And when I put log in sheetSwipeEnabled condition, the good value is recovered.
But unfortunatly, nothing happening, the bottomsheet does'nt expand anymore. What did I miss?

We can only detect swipes based on finger offset while touching the draggable header, and then set sheetSwipeEnabled to true

That's the solution I'm trying to implement by adding .pointerInput(Unit) {detectVerticalDragGestures { change, dragAmount -> if dragAmount>5 myVariable = true} on the header and manage sheetSwipeEnabled with that
